# Playfab - ReferenceError: "Promise" is not defined

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-apps-script

I'm creating a new little project in Google Spreadsheets to get some data from Playfab servers for a game in Kongregate. Playfab provides a Javascript API to work:

https://download.playfab.com/PlayFabClientApi.js

I will use the function

But when I try to run my first test I get the error message:

```
ReferenceError: "Promise" no está definido. (línea 33, archivo "Código")
```

After some research I readed that Promise is not supported by GAS (Google Apps Script), but somewhere I readed V8 could use promises... I'm little lost, could you help me a little to make this work?

My code in my project:

```
// Load JavaScript from External Server
var url = "https://download.playfab.com/PlayFabClientApi.js";
var javascript = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
var token = "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111";
var kongID = "1111111";
eval(javascript);
/* ######################################################################## */
/* ######################## MENU FUNCTION ################################# */
/* ######################################################################## */
function onOpen(){
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('PLAYFAB MENU');

  menu.addItem('FirstCallPlayfab', 'PlayFabAPICall')
  .addToUi(); 
}

function PlayFabAPICall() {
  PlayFab.settings.titleId = "E3FA";
  var loginRequest = {
    // Currently, you need to look up the correct format for this object in the API-docs:
    // https://api.playfab.com/documentation/Client/method/LoginWithCustomID
    TitleId: PlayFab.settings.titleId,
    AuthTicket: token,
    CreateAccount: false,
    KongregateId: kongID,
  };

  PlayFabClientSDK.LoginWithKongregate(loginRequest, LoginCallback);
}

var LoginCallback = function (result, error) {
  if (result !== null) {
    Logger.log("Congratulations, you made your first successful API call!");
  }
  else if (error !== null) {
    Logger.log("Something went wrong with your first API call.\n" +
    "Here's some debug information:\n" +
    PlayFab.GenerateErrorReport(error));
  }
}
```

The function LoginWithKongregate in the API file:

```
LoginWithKongregate: function (request, callback, customData, extraHeaders) {
    request.TitleId = PlayFab.settings.titleId ? PlayFab.settings.titleId : request.TitleId; if (!request.TitleId) throw PlayFab._internalSettings.errorTitleId;
    // PlayFab._internalSettings.authenticationContext can be modified by other asynchronous login attempts
    // Deep-copy the authenticationContext here to safely update it
    var authenticationContext = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(PlayFab._internalSettings.authenticationContext));
    var overloadCallback = function (result, error) {
        if (result != null) {
            if(result.data.SessionTicket != null) {
                PlayFab._internalSettings.sessionTicket = result.data.SessionTicket;
            }
            if (result.data.EntityToken != null) {
                PlayFab._internalSettings.entityToken = result.data.EntityToken.EntityToken;
            }
            // Apply the updates for the AuthenticationContext returned to the client
            authenticationContext = PlayFab._internalSettings.UpdateAuthenticationContext(authenticationContext, result);
            PlayFab.ClientApi._MultiStepClientLogin(result.data.SettingsForUser.NeedsAttribution);
        }
        if (callback != null && typeof (callback) === "function")
            callback(result, error);
    };
    PlayFab._internalSettings.ExecuteRequestWrapper("/Client/LoginWithKongregate", request, null, overloadCallback, customData, extraHeaders);
    // Return a Promise so that multiple asynchronous calls to this method can be handled simultaneously with Promise.all()
    return new Promise(function(resolve){resolve(authenticationContext);});
},
```

Comment: In the current stage, "Promise" cannot be used at Google Apps Script of the server side, yet. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features) If you want to run the Javascript, for example, how about using Web Apps, side bar and dialog? In this case, the Javascript is run at the client side.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, Tanaike. Could you give me some example, please? (I never used web apps, or at least i dont know them with that name.)

Comment: Thank you for replying. Is this search useful? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+web+apps

Comment: Not so much. I haven't a good base of knowledge in Google apps: I used it like a javascript macro for spreadsheets to do things until I found this problem. Maybe is easier to copy the API and change/delete the promises with another thing?

Comment: Can I ask you about how do you want to run the script? If you want to run the script by the time-driven trigger, it cannot be achieved. If you want to run the script by opening the Google Docs and Web Apps by users, it can be achieved.

Comment: I want to put the call of the script in a custom menu in a spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your comment, I proposed a workaround as an answer. Could you please confirm it? Because I have not token, I cannot test this script. If this didn't work and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to run the script of `PlayFabAPICall()` with `https://download.playfab.com/PlayFabClientApi.js`.
- You want to run the script from the custom menu.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? Unfortunately, in the current stage, "Promise" cannot be used at Google Apps Script of the server side, yet. So as the current workaround, I propose to use the custom dialog and sidebar. In this sample script, a custom dialog is used. The flow of this script is as follows. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

1. Open Spreadsheet.
2. Run the script of `openDialog()` from the custom menu.
3. Open a dialog and `index.html` is run.

   - In this case, `index.html` is run at your browser.

### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor. `Code.gs` and `index.html` are script and html, respectively.

#### Code.gs: Google Apps Script

```
function onOpen(){
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('PLAYFAB MENU');
  menu.addItem('FirstCallPlayfab', 'openDialog').addToUi(); 
}

function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index.html");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'sample');
}
```

#### index.html: HTML and Javascript

```
<script src="https://download.playfab.com/PlayFabClientApi.js"></script>
<script>
  function PlayFabAPICall() {
    PlayFab.settings.titleId = "E3FA";
    var loginRequest = {
      // Currently, you need to look up the correct format for this object in the API-docs:
      // https://api.playfab.com/documentation/Client/method/LoginWithCustomID
      TitleId: PlayFab.settings.titleId,
      AuthTicket: token,
      CreateAccount: false,
      KongregateId: kongID,
    };

    PlayFabClientSDK.LoginWithKongregate(loginRequest, LoginCallback);
  }

  var LoginCallback = function (result, error) {
    if (result !== null) {
      console.log("Congratulations, you made your first successful API call!");
    }
    else if (error !== null) {
      console.log("Something went wrong with your first API call.\n" +
      "Here's some debug information:\n" +
      PlayFab.GenerateErrorReport(error));
    }
  }

  PlayFabAPICall();
</script>
```

### Note:

- Before you run the script, please set `AuthTicket: token,` and `KongregateId: kongID`.

### References:

- [Basic JavaScript features](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features)
- [Custom dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs)
- [Javascript Getting Started](https://api.playfab.com/docs/getting-started/javascript-getting-started)

Comment: I tested this code, adding my token and KongId
I got this message after execute the Menu option:

Ro {message: "There was an error during the transport or process…this request. Error code = 10, Path = /wardeninit", name: "TransportError", stack: "TransportError: There was an error during the tran…/478339065-warden_bin_i18n_warden__es.js:181:252)"}

I searched it, but I cannot understand really well why is this appearing..

Comment: @Barragán Louisenbairn Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About the error messages, I cannot test this situation. So I cannot comment about the error. This sample script is for ``Could you give me some example, please?`` in your comment.

Comment: @Barragán Louisenbairn But in this sample script, Javascript of ``PlayFabClientApi.js`` is correctly run at the opened dialog. If the Javascript has no bugs, the reason of the issue might be the authorization. So can you check the official document at [here](https://api.playfab.com/docs/getting-started/javascript-getting-started)? I apologize that I cannot help you about the issue occurred after you ran the ``PlayFabClientApi.js``. If you want, I can remove my answer. At that time, please tell me.

Comment: Is working now, my fault when copying. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Barragán Louisenbairn Wow! Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.